# How to make a recursive compile time variadic struct template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

Im trying to make a variadic template in c++ to create a static(non-dynamic allocation) struct defined by arguments of a template.

I tried to google that during 3 days but I think the documentation and my ability to formulate my queries ends here.

This what im trying to go for:

```
myTemplate<1,5,2,8> myinstance;
```

myInstance would give me this:

`myinstance { int[1], int[5], int[2], int[8] };`

So how can you achive this, using variadic template in c++ ?
I know already about partial specialisation and that kind of stuff but the documentation is lacking in term of recursion.

Thanks.

Comment: your `myinstance` isnt valid code

Comment: Could you tell what you are trying to do? Seems like an XY problem to me.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek Im trying to create a template that lets me define a struct at compile time with fixed size arrays defined by the template's parameters

Comment: @ÉmerickPoulin - what about if some integer coincide? I mean: `myTemplate<1,2,1>` should contain one or two arrays of size `1`?

Comment: two arrays since each object in the array will be a polymorphic class instance, im using int for the sake of the underlying problem currently facced

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `std::tuple`:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <array>

template<std::size_t... ns>
struct foo {
    std::tuple<std::array<int, ns>...> contents;
};

foo<1, 5, 2, 8> my_foo;

int main() {
    std::get<1>(my_foo.contents)[3] = 4;
}
```